# Unexpected infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

This code runs for infinity, why?

```
    function f(n){
        i=0;
        if (n==2){
            while(i<2){
                f(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

if n!=2 the function should do nothing
and if n equals 2 the function calls f(0) and f(1) so it should stop after that
but you only get infinite loop when you run it.

any one could tell why?

**edit:** there is nothing outside the function.

and no need for better code.Just asking why.

Comment: because `i` is global?

Comment: Because every time `f` is called, it's using the *same* `i` value.  Every time, `i` is re-set to `0`, so it keeps looping.  You never break out of the `while` loop ran the 1st time `f(2)` is called.

Comment: If this is your way of trying to understand JS scope, try and find a simpler example to start with.

Comment: "var is not optional" I think it would make a great song title.

Comment: There is no i outside.just this.

Comment: In JavaScript, if you don't declare the variable with `var`, it creates an implicit global.  If you use `var` it is scoped to the function it is declared in.

Comment: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) this explains all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix it by changing

```
i=0;
```

to

```
var i=0;
```

Your `i` variable is global (or at least its scope is external to `f`, so it's shared by all calls of the function). When `n` is initially `2`, you enter the loop and this loop always resets `i` to `0` just before the increment. The sequence you have is thus

```
i = 0 // start of f
// enters loop for the first time with f(0)
i = 0 // start of f
i = 1 // i++
i <2 so loop again
i = 0 // start of f
i = 1 // i++
i <2 so loop again
i = 0 // start of f
i = 1 // i++
i <2 so loop again
i = 0 // start of f
i = 1 // i++
i <2 so loop again
i = 0 // start of f
i = 1 // i++
...
```

Comment: Every time `f` is called, the global `i` (because there is no `var` in front of it) is "reset" to 0

Comment: Seems to me like it'll still be infinite if `f` is ever invoked with `2`, but for a different reason.

Comment: Oh, I guess not. The condition is `< 2`.

Comment: i don't see why `i` is global even if it doesn't exist outside `f`

Comment: @MIE When you don't declare a variable with `var`, then you reuse an external one (a global one if you never declared it).

Answer (score 2):

`i` is global.  Declare it with `var` instead to keep it local to each instance.  Otherwise, it is constantly reset to `0`, so your `while` loop never ends.

Answer (score 1):

Because you got f(i) all the time with i = 0. So when you are doing a loop, you are going to do f(0) indefinitly ! (same for every i) Just put a var on your i to stop your loop

Comment: and ? Just before you got f(i) with i = 0 every time... Look:
n = 0
function f(0){
        i=0;
        if (n==2){
            while(i<2){
                f(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
you are going to do f(0) and f(1).
In f(0) you're going to do .... f(0) and f(1), ...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, `i=0` is global variable,  reason for `f(i)` setting the value each and every time along with Global variable, so you need to use  `var i=0;` for initialize the `i` every time.

```
    function f(n){
        var i=0;
        if (n==2){
            while(i<2){
                f(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is better. The question is why?

Answer (score 0):

Every time `f()` is called, `i` is set back to `0`.  Since you didn't do `var i = 0`, that means that `i` is global!  Every time `f()` is called, the *same* value of `i` is used.

When you call `f(2)`, you start a `while` loop.  Every time you call `f(i)`, you are re-setting `i` to `0`.  So the `while` loop never ends.

You need to make `i` local:

```
function f(n){
    var i=0;
    if (n==2){
        while(i<2){
            f(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This way every time `f()` is called, it creates its own `i` variable.